# How would I write to a CSV file from a python dictionary of dictionaries while some values are empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary of dictionaries and have date stored that i need to write to a CSV file.

the problem i'm having is that some of the dictionaries from the file i have read don't contain any information for that particular ID. So my CSV file column are not lined up properly .

example

```
 d["first1"]["title"] = founder
  d["first1"]["started"] = 2005
  d["second1"]["title"] = CEO
  d["second1"]["favcolour"] = blue
```

and so when i use the following code:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
 ln = [key]
        for ikey, ivalue in value.iteritems():
           ln.append(ikey)
           ln.extend([v for v in ivalue])
        writer.writerow(ln)
```

my CSV file will have all the information but the "started" and "favcolour" are in the same column i want it so that the columns only contain one .

Thanks all in advance

Comment: can you show your current and expected output formats?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion:

```
d = {"first1": {"title": 'founder', "started": 2005}, "second1": {"title": 'CEO', "favcolour": 'blue'}}

columns = []
output = []
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    for ikey, ivalue in value.iteritems():
        if ikey not in columns:
            columns.append(ikey)
    ln = []
    for col in columns:
        if col not in value:
            ln.append('')
        else:
            ln.append(value[col])

    output.append(ln)

with open('file', 'w') as fl:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fl)
    csv_writer.writerow(columns)
    for ln in output:
        print ln
        csv_writer.writerow(ln)
```

file:

```
started,title,favcolour
2005,founder
,CEO,blue
```

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't need to be human-readable, you can use alternatively `pickle`:

```
import pickle

# Write:
with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(d, handle)

# Read:
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
  d = pickle.load(handle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DictWriter` class in `csv` to easily append what would be a sparse dictionary into a CSV. The only caveat is you need to know all the possible fields at the beginning.

```
import csv

data = { "first": {}, "second": {} }
data["first"]["title"] = "founder"
data["first"]["started"] = 2005
data["second"]["title"] = "CEO"
data["second"]["favcolour"] = "blue"


fieldNames = set()

for d in data:
  for key in data[d].keys():
    # Add all possible keys to fieldNames, beacuse fieldNames is
    # a set, you can't have duplicate values
    fieldNames.add(key)


with open('csvFile.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
  # Initialize DictWriter with the list of fieldNames
  # You can sort fieldNames to whatever order you wish the CSV
  # headers to be in.
  writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=list(fieldNames))

  # Add Header to the CSV file
  writer.writeheader()

  # Iterate through all sub-dictionaries
  for d in data:
    # Add the sub-dictionary to the csv file
    writer.writerow(data[d])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas works really well for things like this, so if it's an option, I would recommend it.

```
import pandas as pd

#not necessary, but for me it's usually easier to work with a list of dicts than dicts
my_list = [my_dict[key] for key in my_dict]
# When you pass a list of dictionaries to pandas DataFrame class, it will take care of 
#alignment issues for you, but if you're wanting to do something specific 
#with None values, you will need to further manipulate the frame
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
df.to_csv('file_path_to_save_to')
```